# Why does std::optional::value_or() take a U&& rather than T&&?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or), we can see `std::optional` takes a default value of `U&&` rather than `T&&`.

It makes me incapable of writing the following code:

```
std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> opt;
opt.value_or({1, 2}); // does not compile
opt.value_or(std::make_pair(1, 2)); // compiles
```

However, I find there is no benefit to using `U&&`, since `U` must be convertible to `T` here.

So, consider the following code, if we have some type `U` which differs from `T`, then there will be no perfect match. However, by performing an implicit cast, we can still resolve our call:

```
template< class U >
constexpr T value_or( T&& default_value ) const&;
```

I have the following code to test if a template function can take an argument which needs an extra implicit casting to make a perfect match, and it compiles:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <optional>
#include <map>

struct A {
    int i = 1;
};

struct B {
    operator A() const {
        return A{2};
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct C {
    void f(T && x) {
        printf("%d\n", x.i);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto b = B();
    C<A> c;
    c.f(b);
}
```

Comment: To avoid to do extra construction with call similar to `std::optional<std::string>("some string").value_or("c-string");`

Comment: The answers explain why the proposed change is wrong. But the correct change would be to add the default template argument: `typename U = T`. No idea why that wasn't done.

Comment: Unrelated, but simplifies things: `opt.value_or(std::pair{1, 2});`

Comment: Another unrelated comment: This Is is a great Q&A. It's a very good question with three very good answers and I've upvoted everything. The only pity is that it shows up on the list of "Unanswered" questions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do I need to accept one of these answers? I find it hard to pick the best because I think all of them are very good...

Comment: @calvin No, you don't need to. It's just that the question shows up in the list of unanswered questions all the time and this question seems particularly well answered :-) I _suggest_ upvoting them all if you find them all good and then picking one that stands out a little ... even if just a tad. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 32):

> I find there it no benefit by using U&&, since U must be convertible to T here.

`U` must be convertible to `T`, but a conversion can be expensive. Taking a forwarding reference (`U&&`) avoids performing that conversion if the argument is not used (if the object contains a value).

The same cppreference page says `value_or` is equivalent to:
`bool(*this) ? **this : static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(default_value))`.
Here, `static_cast<T>` performs the conversion, but it is only performed if `bool(*this)` is `false`.

Answer (score 20):

It is to allow perfect forwarding.  If the signature were

```
constexpr T value_or( T&& default_value ) const&;
```

then `T` is not something that will be deduced, it is known from the class instantiation, meaning `T&& default_value` is just a plain rvalue reference to whatever `T` is.

By using

```
template< class U >
constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value ) const&;
```

The `U` needs to be deduced making it a forwarding reference.

Comment: or it can be simply overloaded?

Comment: @appleapple It could be, but Nelfeal points out in there answer why you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: true (was about to edit my comment to mention @Jarod42's comment in OP).

Comment: @appleapple actually has a good point, you could provide both the template and additional overloads for T (like `constexpr T value_or( T&& default_value ) const&;`). Only perfect matches would select the non-template overloads. However, I doubt that would offer much value.

Comment: Ok, so actually I can think of `U&&` as a universal reference. That makes sense.

Comment: @calvin Yes.  They've changed the name to forwarding reference.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the type isn't defaulted to `T` though, which would allow the example to compile...

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure why it doesn't have a default set.  It could be an oversight but it almost feels intentional.  I'll try to see if something is mentioned in the optional proposal

Comment: @Deduplicator After finding [this](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3672.html#rationale.value_or), it looks like it just might not have been considered.  [The original proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1878.htm) is back from 2005-08-29 so they might not even known about the whole `{ ... }` being a non-deduced types, or that the syntax was even going to be a thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike That sounds reasonable. Too bad it didn't trigger a change when [`std::expected::value_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected/value_or) was added though. Instead, [the proposal for that](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0323r12.html#value-or) simply says: _"The function member `value_or()` has the same semantics than `optional`"_.

Answer (score 9):

As a concrete example

```
template<class T>
struct constructor {
  operator T()const{
    return f();
  }
  std::function<T()> f;
  constructor( std::function<T()> fin = []{return T{};} ):
    f(std::move(fin))
  {}
};
template<class F>
constructor(F) -> constructor<std::invoke_result_t<F>>;
```

Now I have an `std::optional<std::vector<int>> bob;`.  I can do:

```
auto v = bob.value_or( constructor{ []{ return std::vector<int>(10000); } } );
```

here, if `bob` has a value, we return it.  Otherwise, we create a 10,000 element vector and return that.

Because we defer the conversion from `U&&` to `T` for the false branch, we don't have to allocate the 10,000 sized vector unless we need to return it.

Now, I find that adding a `T&&` overload in these cases is well worth it, and the standard library doesn't do it enough, mostly for the reason you describe -- it permits `{}` based construction.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your point. If I use `T&&`, then the conversion must be done before we pass the `default_value` to `value_or`. However, we can defer the conversion to when we really needs it if we use `U&&`.

Comment: However, I think a better idea is to use `or_else` in this case, which is also recommended way in other languages like Rust.

Comment: @calvin `or_else` doesn't exist in C++17 though - but it will come in C++23.